# Why setTimeout is not triggering inside useCallback ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

Want to write a function that triggers if user is scolling, but it seems that setTimeout isnt being triggered in this case. It should set the state to false when user is not scrolling.

```js
  const handleScollTab = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log('trriiii');
      dispatch(getScrollYTrigger(true));

      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(getScrollYTrigger(false));
      }, 1000);
      clearTimeout(timer);
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScollTab);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScollTab);
    };
  }, [handleScollTab]);
```

Comment: Will it be possible to host it on codepen or sanbox?

Comment: You're clearing the timeout _immediately_ after setting it, the callback will never be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-feather-xmdzm?file=/src/App.js

You can do like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = React.useState(false);
  const setTimerRef = React.useRef();
  const handleScollTab = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("trriiii");
    setTrigger(true);
    console.log("set true");
    if (setTimerRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(setTimerRef.current);
      setTimerRef.current = null;
    }

    setTimerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("set false");
      setTrigger(false);
      clearTimeout(setTimerRef.current);
      setTimerRef.current = null;
    }, 1000);
  }, [setTimerRef]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScollTab);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScollTab);
    };
  }, [handleScollTab]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

By doing this you can effectively clearTimeout that created by previous handler calls. And clear last one as well.

Comment: There should be a `clearTimeout` inside the `useEffect` cleanup function IMO (and resetting the ref too). Also, I don't see the need of clearing the timeout inside the `setTimeout` itself

Answer (score 0):

you clearTimeout instant after setTimout() before await 1000

for fix remove clearTimeout()

Comment: Removing the `clearTimeout` call would definitely not cause a memory leak.